# Make IntelliJ IDEA run JUnit tests with -parameters javac option

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, junit4

Is there a way to ensure the `-parameters` option is passed whenever running JUnit tests from IntelliJ IDEA?
If it's impossible to set globally, it would even help to set it for specific Run/Debug configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-parameters` option is a Java compiler option, so it affects how the code is compiled, not how it is run. You can add it in Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler | Additional command line parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it that's way : 
[image]